# after creating a model file can we evaluate the same model file in weka for another classifier

Tags: weka

I created a model file in weka for classification using the naive bayes and MLP (Multi Layer Peceptron).**I want to run the same file for bagging is it possible?**

Comment: can you give more information about what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the same file you can't. What you can do is use the same parameters in your classifiers and build the bagging.

Remember bagging is under weka.classifiers.meta. All the ensemble methods are a meta classifier

See the [JavaDoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/meta/Bagging.html) to see more information.